# How to add a plugin to TraceCompass RCP?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a plugin for the Trace Compass application, this plugin works fine with the Trace Compass Eclipse plugins but I can't seem to make it work with the RCP Trace Compass application. Could someone give me some information on how a plugin can be added to a RCP application ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Copy it into the `dropins` subdirectory of the installation directory.

Comment: There is no dropins subdirectory for this RCP application unfortunately.

Comment: Please extend your question with the download link and which version you are using. If it is a non-p2-based RCP application, you have to copy the plug-in into the `plugins` subdirectory. To use _Help > Install New Software..._ an update site that contains the feature with the plugin is required.

Comment: The use of an update site with my feature worked. Thank you howlger.